# Select Jenkins Node via command line

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

All our jenkins nodes have various labels.  Jenkins jobs are restricted to some assortment of those labels.  From the command line (Jenkins CLI), I want to override that restriction for a specific build which I am kicking off from the command line.

That is, for this one build which I am kicking off from the command line, I want Jenkins to use node ABC even though the build is restricted to a label which does not include node ABC.

We do not use piplines

Comment: What kind of job? For pipeline jobs you could add a parameter and use that in the `agent` statement.